# Watch World Cup on Apple TV

Tags: appletv

How do you watch the World Cup on an Apple TV? Can somebody give me a tutorial with pictures? I do not have any cable subscription whatsoever.

I heard that you can watch it on ESPN on Apple TV, but I want to confirm that this is true.

Extra note: I have the Apple TV with the black console. (see below)
[image]

In other words, I have the latest version of Apple TV.

Comment: I don't have an answer for your problem, but even the ESPN app on the Apple TV will require a cable subscription.

Comment: The ESPN app on Apple TV requires a cable subscription to ESPN to function fully.

Comment: What country is your Apple ID associated with? How you purchase ESPN varies and in the us, you basically need to pay for cable to view the World Cup using the espn app on Apple TV.

Comment: Which World Cup?

Answer (score 1):

I do something different.

I am in Canada, so I am using the CBC's (free) World Cup app on my iPhone, which gives access to live streams of matches. Using AirPlay I stream those to my AppleTV.

The quality is pretty awesome.

You don't mention where you live, but maybe there is an app available in your region too?

Comment: I live in the USA.

Answer (score 0):

*Depending on the cable provider and location*, if you are a "member of household" which has a cable subscription to ESPN you should be able to use the ESPN app to watch the World Cup.

As an example: If you are a college student and your parents have Comcast cable subscription to ESPN.  Have your "parents" set up an Comcast email account / login for you. You should be able to use that email/login & password to verify the cable account.  Then you should be able to access ESPN app content when you are away from home.